# How can I join several plots a single figure using a Table?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

It is possible to joint different kind of plot using a Table, The idea is to have a single plot. I have been trying using Show function y. But I can not get it.  So It is possible also to add independently captions for each figure.

Here it is the code

```
L = 15; pp = 100; uv1 = {y -> 0 , k -> 1}; uv2 = { k -> 0.5} ;

Bb[x_, y_, n_] = BesselJ[n, k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]; 

graf1 =Table[ Plot[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv1, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotLabel -> {tit, tit1, tit2 }], {n, 0, 2}];

graf2 = Table[Plot3D[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv2 , {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, "Bessel"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotRange -> Full, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -2, 1.3}], {n, 0, 2}]; 

graf3 = Table[DensityPlot[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv2, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> pp,    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {n, 0, 2}];
```

I try using

```
Show[{graf1,graf2,graf3}]
```

Comment: Have you seen `GraphicsRow[]`?

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
GraphicsGrid[{graf1, graf2, graf3}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank!.  Yes, it works perfectly to put all the pictures together, but I still do not know how to show the title for each figure. Any comment will be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
titles1 = {"title1-1", "title1-2", "title1-3"};
titles2 = {"title2-1", "title2-2", "title2-3"};
titles3 = {"title3-1", "title3-2", "title3-3"};
graf1 = Table[Plot[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv1, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> Full, 
    PlotLabel -> titles1[[n + 1]]], {n, 0, 2}];
graf2 = Table[Plot3D[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv2, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, "Bessel"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotRange -> Full, ViewPoint -> {1.5, -2, 1.3}, 
    PlotLabel -> titles2[[n + 1]]], {n, 0, 2}];
graf3 = Table[DensityPlot[Bb[x, y, n] /. uv2, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> pp, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLabel -> titles3[[n + 1]]], {n, 0, 2}];
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Thanks. This a very awesome and elegant solution!

Comment: @irondonio, if this answers your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I try as a possible solution

```
ouplot = TableForm[{graf1, graf2, graf3}, TableHeadings -> {TextCell[StringJoin[{"Plot ", ToString@#}], FontSize -> 12] & /@ { cut, 3 D, 2 D} , 
TextCell[StringJoin[{"m = ", ToString@#}], FontSize -> 12] & /@ 
 Range[0, 3]}, TableAlignments -> Center, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]
```

However, I would like to add more details to show the function detail also a  title, a legend this should improve the figure more.